# Custom Spelling in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does Google Chrome allow any manipulation of the default spelling lexicons? I've searched for material based on this and cant find any. Trying to develop a speller that works in Google Chrome web apps like Google Documents. Currently, my spell checking app won't work in any text field or area related to Google docs or Office 365. Additionally, I have my own word list I want to incorporate into Chrome's speller? Can that be done? Can a third party custom dictionary be added to Google Chrome's spelling tool? Simply looking for resources that explain this as I can not find any.

Answer (score 6):

After [a quick search on the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=spell%20check%20cr=Platform-Extensions&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), I found [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135628&q=spell%20check%20cr=Platform-Extensions&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) that adds a (badly documented) feature to the extension platform.

According to the [commit message](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135628#c12), you can add a new dictionary using the "spellcheck" key in the [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) file.

```
{
  "name": "Dictionary Test",
  "description": "Load a spellcheck dictionary.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "spellcheck": {
    "dictionary_language": "testEnglish",
    "dictionary_locale": "te",
    "dictionary_format": "hunspell",
    "dictionary_path": "testEnglish.bdic"
  }
}
```

Because documentation on this feature is non-existent, you have to read Chromium's source code if you want to know how to use this feature at all. Here's the diff for the commit that added the new feature to the extension API: https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/download/issue14064004_10001.diff

And here's some documentation about the format of the dictionaries: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries